# Loading data from a dynamic csv file ( file data changes daily/weekly) into a Oracle SQL table

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-loader

I have a requirement to load data into a oracle SQL table from a csv file (comma separated). This csv file data changes daily and is provided by other team. After the data is loaded, i will use that table to join with an existing table to get the required report.

My Table :

```
CREATE TABLE CC_TEST 
(
  USERNAME VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL 
, column2 VARCHAR2(30)  NOT NULL
, column3 VARCHAR2(30)  Primary key 
);
```

Input CSV File :

```
USERNAME,column2,Column3
CC1234,adsfasdf,AB34568
CC1864,etwetwee,AB78966
CC7686,knblfklf,AB90867
```

Any inputs would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: create .ctl as following... OPTIONS (SKIP=1)
load data
infile '/home/oracle/filename.csv'
append
into table CC_TEST
fields terminated by ","
( USERNAME,column2,Column3)

Comment: Thank you @scott yu.    Can we run this from Sql developer tool and also can this be set to run on daily basis as the .csv file changes daily ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is your table:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE CC_TEST
  2  (
  3    USERNAME VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL
  4  , column2 VARCHAR2(30)  NOT NULL
  5  , column3 VARCHAR2(30)  Primary key
  6  );

Table created.
```

Control file (for simplicity, I included sample data into it - see the `begindata` section. You'd use the `infile` parameter with the file name):

```
options (skip=1)
load data 
infile *
replace
into table cc_test
fields terminated by ','
trailing nullcols
( 
username,
column2,
column3
)

begindata
USERNAME,column2,Column3
CC1234,adsfasdf,AB34568
CC1864,etwetwee,AB78966
CC7686,knblfklf,AB90867
```

Testing:

```
SQL> $sqlldr scott/tiger control=test24.ctl log=test24.log

SQL*Loader: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Pet Pro 25 19:49:43 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Commit point reached - logical record count 3

SQL> select * from cc_test;

USERNAME                       COLUMN2                        COLUMN3
------------------------------ ------------------------------ -----------------------
CC1234                         adsfasdf                       AB34568
CC1864                         etwetwee                       AB78966
CC7686                         knblfklf                       AB90867

SQL>
```

---

As of your questions asked as comments: SQL*Loader is utility that runs on operating system command prompt. As you'll get new data on daily basis, I suggest you create a *batch file* (on MS Windows, that would be the `.bat`) and put `sqlldr` executable call into it. Then create a **job** (on MS Windows, that's Task Scheduler) which would run the .bat script on schedule you set.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking how to load a file and you got responses to that question. But is that really needed for your business requirement ?
In oracle you can define external tables. Define your csv file as a external table and just use it in a query just as it were a normal table. No need to load, no need to maintain an intermediate table. Just define the external table and run your report whenever it is needed. Tim Halls' article shows exactly how to do that: https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/external-tables-9i

Answer (score 0):

run sqlldr as sqlldr username/password control=testcs.ctl